# Only one process must execute a code portion at a time

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, synchronization

I am sorry I am repeating a question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5687837/monitor-implementation-in-c but not getting a solution as yet. I have probably asked the question incorrectly.

Say I have a code portion B. A parent process spawns a number of child processes to execute code B but I would like only one process to be inside code portion B at a time. How can I do it in C on Linux platform?

Thanks for your help

An edit. Not threads but process.

Comment: I'd like to suggest that you should be locking your _data_, not your _code_. Identify the shared data and make sure locks are in place to protect the shared data. Trying to lock your _code_ is a quick way to write spaghetti. :)

Comment: Your other question had a fair number of deleted answers, including [`pthread_cond_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_cond_wait.html) -- but sadly, the owner didn't leave a comment about _why_ he deleted it. It seemed like a useful starting point to me..

Comment: Actually my pthread_cond_wait answer mysteriously disappeared.  I don't understand what happened to it.

Comment: @Seth...I too saw another answer initially but when i open yesterday...I saw there was only one answer as you said yours "mysteriously" disappeared

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a mutex.

```
pthread_mutex_t mutexsum;
pthread_mutex_init(&mutexsum, NULL);
pthread_mutex_lock (&mutexsum);
// Critical code
pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutexsum);
```

If you are serious about it being multiple processes instead of multiple threads, the mutex needs to be stored in a shared memory segment.

Comment: And for putting mutexes into shared memory, look into [`shmget(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/shmget) and friends.

Comment: for shared segments, I think the `shm_open` interface together with `mmap` is easier to handle.

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to have exactly one child running at any point of time, then why spawn all the children processes all at once?

When a child process ends, a `SIGCHLD` is issued, you can write your own handler for this signal and call spawn from the handler. Then you have one new child process created when one perishes -- only one child process running. Below is a hack (useless, just for demo) to achieve this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>    

void spawn(void){

    pid_t child_pid=fork();

    if(child_pid > 0){
        printf("new child created by %d !\n",getpid()); 
        sleep(1);
    }else if(child_pid == 0){
        printf("child %d created !\n",getpid());

    }else{
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


void handler(int sigval){
    spawn();    
}

int main(void){
    signal(SIGCHLD,handler);
    spawn();
    return 0;
}
```